# Linear Algebra - Invertible matrices and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be any $n \times n$ invertible matrix, defined over the integer numbers. 
Let assume that $A^{-1}$ (Inverse of A) is also defined over the integer numbers.

Prove that $\det A\in\{-1,+1\}$.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$det(A)det(A^{-1}) = det(I) = 1$. You also know that $det(A) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $det(A^{-1}) \in \mathbb{Z}$. See what you can do with that.

Comment: $det(A)det(A^{-1}$=1 appiles to all invertible matrix I don't understand how to becomes why in this case $det(A) \in \{-1,+1\}$, can you explain please?

Comment: @JaVaPG If a matrix has integer coefficients, then its determinant is an integer number.

Comment: @JaVaPG So you know that you have two integers that multiply to 1. The special thing here is that they are integers. What possible integers multiply to 1?

Comment: That the determinant is an integer is clear to me, but I don't understand why it should be $\{1,-1\}$
Only 1*1=1 $\rightarrow$ only 1 multiply to 1

Comment: @JaVaPG So you know that $det(A)det(A^{-1}) = 1$. Then you can conclude that the only values for the determinants of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are pairs of integers that multiply to 1. Are you with me this far?

Comment: @JaVaPG Then, look at these pairs. What are they? (There should be two). They are your possible values for the determinant.

Comment: @Johanna Ok, I think I got it, since $A$ and $A^{-1}$ defined over integers the only integers that could be found in the matrix are 1. else in order to find the $A^{-1}$ we would need to use division meaning that it should be defined it over real number instand of integer number, right?

Comment: @JaVaPG Exactly, and there are only two possible values for the determinant that satisfy that condition.

Comment: @Johanna I only seem to think of matrix that $detA=1$ could you please give an example for a matrix that appiles these terms that the $detA=-1$?

Comment: @JaVaPG [[1,0],[0,-1]]

Answer (score 2):

$\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=\det(AA^{-1})=\det(I)=1$